# How can I reuse code that I have created to hold a select list item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code that is a view model in MVC

```
public class adminQViewModel
    {

        public SubTopic SubTopic { get; set; }
        public Answer   Answer { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Status")]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusType
        {
            get
            {
                return new[]
                    {
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
                        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Draft" },
                    };
            }
        }
    }
```

I use the same combination of value and text in other places when I retrieve values and display the text equivalents. Is there some way that I can encapsulate this combination of value : texzt and use it in other places plus use it for my select drop down lists?

One example is when I return data that's presented in a view. The data contains values for status codes such as 0,1,2 and 3. However I want to display the textual value. I could create another lookup or hardcode but then I would be duplicating the way the data is stored in two different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use SelectLists and the helper method `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new StatusSelectList())` in your view.

```
public class StatusSelectList : SelectList
{
    private static Dictionary<int, string> data = new Dictionary<int, string>
        { 
            { 0, "Release" }, 
            { 1, "Beta" }, 
            { 2, "Alpha" }, 
            { 3, "Draft" } 
        };

    public StatusSelectList()
        : base(data, "Key", "Value")
    {
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Display the label for current status value:

1. Decorate you property in the view model with the UIHint attribute: `[UIHint("DropDownList")]`.
2. Set the select list to `ViewBag.SelectLists = new Dictionary<string, SelectList> { "Status", new StatusSelectList() };`
3. Display the label for current status value with `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Status)`.

Comment: That works good but in the view I just want the text to appear without giving the user a dropdown. The particular view just contains a report and is read only. As I iterate over 100's of lines of data then that would mean 100s of drop down lists :-(

Comment: I updated the solution to display labels for current status value.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it once in a private property and then return it with every subsequent request.  This is called [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading):

```
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> _statusType;

    [DisplayName("Status")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusType
    {
        get
        {
            if (_statusType == null) 
            {
                _statusType = new[] {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Release" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Beta" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Alpha" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Draft" },
               };
            }

            return _statusType;
        }
    }
```

Also, if you're reusing the same list between different user sessions, then it may make sense to make it a static property, so that it's instantiated once and lives on until the application pool is recycled/restarted.

**UPDATE**:

You can use a little bit of LINQ to retrieve the text you want.  For example, to get "Alpha" based on value 2:

```
string text = StatusType.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Value == "2");
```

Comment: I guess what I really want is to somehow be able to use this in other areas of code. For example for the same case where I have var a=2 and I want to print out the characters "Beta" or var a=2 and I want to print out "Alpha". How can I do this kind of a look up given the above?

Comment: The SelectListItem class in MVC requires Value to be a string

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom class:

```
public class StatusType : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>>
{
      private readonly List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> entries = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

    public void Add(int key, string value)
    {
        this.entries.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(key, value));
    }

    public string this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var kvp in this.entries)
            {
                if (string.Compare(kvp.Key, key, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
                {
                    return kvp.Value;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```